# Создание ascii-art при помощи рекурсии

Tags: python, рекурсия

Необходимо написать рекурсивную функцию, которая выводит на экран `ASCII-art` трапецию следующего вида, в зависимости от числа `n`. Пример приведен для `n = 4`.

Теперь суть вопроса: по какой логике должна работать подобная рекурсивная функция? У меня была мысль печатать определенно кол-во пробелов и звездочек, и передавать измененный аргумент дальше по рекурсии, но что должно являться условием выхода из рекурсии, и какое кол-во пробелов ставить я не знаю.

```
       * * 
     * * * * 
   * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: Поправьте ромбик, пожалуйста.

Comment: Так что же все-таки нужно? Ромб (как сказано в тексте вопроса) или трапеция (как нарисовано)?

Comment: нужна вот такая трапеция(n четное)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def draw(n, indent=0):
    if n == 0: return
    draw(n-1, indent+1)
    print("{}{}".format(' ' * 2 * indent, ' '.join('*' * 2 * n)))
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Если совсем примитивно, то у Вас трапеция состоит из двух равносторонних треугольников, стороны которых соответствуют `n`:

```
>>> def f(n):
...   e = 0
...   for i in range(n):
...     e += 1
...     print('  '*(n-e) + ' * *'*e + '  '*(n-e)) 
... 
>>> f(4)
       * *      
     * * * *    
   * * * * * *  
 * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: Только это не рекурсия

Comment: @Александр ага, и трапеция это не ромб

Answer (score 2):

Попытка в хвостовую рекурсию:

```
def draw(n, i=0):
    width = 2 * (i + n)
    stars_count = 2 * i + 2
    indent = (width - stars_count) // 2
    print('  ' * indent + ' *' * stars_count)
    if n <= 1:
        return
    draw(n - 1, i + 1)
```